# How to typehint regular expression within lambda with python mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-re, python-typing

Example:

```py
import re

x = [
    "info_2_mation_1_thing",
    "info_2_mation_5_thing",
    "info_2_mation_2_thing",
    "info_2_mation_3_thing",
    "info_2_mation_13_thing",
    "info_2_mation_4_thing",
]
sorted(x, key=lambda x: int(re.match(r"info_\d_mation_(\d+)_thing", x).group(1)))
```

Gives the error:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:13: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Match[Any]]" has no attribute "group"  [union-attr]
test.py:13: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Match[str]]" has no attribute "group"  [union-attr]
```

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to type this though?

Answer (score 2):

Mypy is actually pointing to a real problem here: the regex might not match, and if it doesn't, trying to access the group will indeed throw.  (i.e. `re.Match` will return `None`).

This is one of two cases: either you know those are the only strings that regex will ever get called with, in which case you know more than mypy does and you just put a `# type: ignore` to tell mypy you really know best; or you are going to run this on real-world data, in which case mypy has found a problem, and you want something like:

```py
try:
    sorted(x, key=lambda x: int(re.match(r"info_\d_mation_(\d+)_thing", x).group(1))) # type: ignore
except AttributeError:
    ...
```

Comment: running `mypy test.py` returns the same error, putting within `try / except` doesn't seem to inform mypy

Comment: yes, sorry, you need to tell mypy to be silent with a comment within the try block

Answer (score 2):

As @2e0byo says in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69463352/13990016), the issue here is that, in general, `re.match` could return a `Match` object, or it could return `None`, and Mypy is warning you about that.

**If you know (for some reason) that this pattern will always match**, you could silence Mypy by adding a `cast` (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)):

```
import re
from typing import cast

x = [
    "info_2_mation_1_thing",
    "info_2_mation_5_thing",
    "info_2_mation_2_thing",
    "info_2_mation_3_thing",
    "info_2_mation_13_thing",
    "info_2_mation_4_thing",
]

result = sorted(
    x,
    key=lambda x: int(cast(re.Match[str], re.match(r"info_\d_mation_(\d+)_thing", x)).group(1))
)
```

Or, you could silence MyPy by adding a `# type: ignore` comment. (It's best to only silence specific mypy errors for a certain line, rather than silencing all mypy errors for a certain line. This is the same as the principle that you should never use a bare `except` in a `try`/`except` block. You can find out the specific kind of error Mypy is raising by using the `--show-error-codes` option. In this case it's the `[union-attr]` code, so we silence only those specific errors using `# type: ignore[union-attr]`.)

```
import re

x = [
    "info_2_mation_1_thing",
    "info_2_mation_5_thing",
    "info_2_mation_2_thing",
    "info_2_mation_3_thing",
    "info_2_mation_13_thing",
    "info_2_mation_4_thing",
]

result = sorted(
    x,
    key=lambda x: int(re.match(r"info_\d_mation_(\d+)_thing", x).group(1)) # type: ignore[union-attr]
)
```

**If you do not know that the pattern will always match**, then Mypy is raising a valid error. In this case, in order to satisfy MyPy, you'll need to introduce some kind of test checking that the result of `re.match` is not `None`. Since `Match` objects are always truthy, it is here safe and idiomatic to test the truthiness of the returned value from `re.match`, even though normally we would test for the presence of `None` using `is`. In this snippet, I've used the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/), which was introduced in Python 3.8:

```
import re

x = [
    "info_2_mation_1_thing",
    "info_2_mation_5_thing",
    "info_2_mation_2_thing",
    "info_2_mation_3_thing",
    "info_2_mation_13_thing",
    "info_2_mation_4_thing",
]

DEFAULT = -1

result = sorted(
    x, 
    key=lambda x: int(m.group(1)) if (m := re.match(r"info_\d_mation_(\d+)_thing", x)) else DEFAULT
)
```

All three of these solutions result in rather long `lambda` functions. One way of abbreviating these functions (and making your code slightly more efficient as a happy side-effect) would be to pre-compile your regex patterns. The third solution I gave above would be refactored as this:

```
import re

x = [
    "info_2_mation_1_thing",
    "info_2_mation_5_thing",
    "info_2_mation_2_thing",
    "info_2_mation_3_thing",
    "info_2_mation_13_thing",
    "info_2_mation_4_thing",
]

DEFAULT = -1
PATTERN = re.compile(r"info_\d_mation_(\d+)_thing")

result = sorted(
    x, 
    key=lambda x: int(m.group(1)) if (m := PATTERN.match(x)) else DEFAULT
)
```

Comment: nice!  didn't know about `typing.cast`, I'm going to remember that